# Pass a dynamic value in the Elasticsearch Painless script params from the Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

I am passing params map in the painless script, that map is type of `<String, Long>`.
The key of the map defines the `id` and the value defines the `foundDate` in epoch Long.

The elastic Document have the raw structure like this :

```
doc:{
     [ "id":11406, // type:Long
      "lastFixed": 1666015888000 // type epoch millis
     ]  // ...mutiple ids and their lastFixed Dates
}
```

I have calculate the average difference between the `foundDate` and `lastFixed` (both are in epoch).

I have build the ES Painless script as below:

```
"script": {
              "source": "(doc['lastFixed'] - params[doc['id']] )/ (1000*60*60)",
              "lang": "expression",
              "params": {
                "11406": 1614084531000,
                "11473": 1073523856000,
                "11549": 1447461154000,
                "43904": 1666015887000,
                "43905": 1666015887000,
                "43906": 1666015887000,
                "43907": 1666015887000,
                "43908": 1666015888000,
                "43909": 1666015888000,
                "43910": 1666015888000
                }
            }
```

For nesting on the array of `id` & `lastFound` date I am using `nest-path-aggr-name` i.e. the nested path.

I want to pass the dynamic value in the params map as it will give the `foundDate` from the map for the same `id` in the Elasticsearch document.

But I am getting the parsing error from ES. I have tired with `param.doc['id']` and `param[]` but both are falling and giving parsing error.

What is the correct way to pass the dynamic value in params map.

Comment: I am confused, could you give an example of what you ate trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

Below is based on my understanding of your issue

I have assumed below mapping for your document.

```
PUT index-name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "nested_field":{
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your question I believe nested_field is of type nested.

**Sample Document**

```
POST index-name/_doc
{
  "nested_field": [
    {
      "id": 11406,
      "lastFixed": 1666015888000
    },
    {
      "id": 11407,
      "lastFixed": 1666015888000
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) to access nested fields.

**Query**

```
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "nest-path-aggr-name": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "nested_field"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_agg": {
          "avg": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                    for(entry in params.entrySet())
                    {
                      if (entry.getKey() == doc['nested_field.id'].value.toString())
                      {
                        return ( doc['nested_field.lastFixed'].value -  entry.getValue())/ (1000*60*60); 
                      }
                    }
                      return 0;
                  """,
              "params": {
                "11406": 1614084531000,
                "11473": 1073523856000,
                "11549": 1447461154000,
                "43904": 1666015887000,
                "43905": 1666015887000,
                "43906": 1666015887000,
                "43907": 1666015887000,
                "43908": 1666015888000,
                "43909": 1666015888000,
                "43910": 1666015888000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to pass the dynamic value in the params map to fetch the respective value. the dynamic value for the params key will be fetched from Elasticsearch document.

Comment: @RushikeshSabde are you referring to these values "11406": 1614084531000,                "11473": 1073523856000, "11549": 1447461154000,"43904": 1666015887000,         "43905": 1666015887000, "43906": 1666015887000, "43907": 1666015887000,
 "43908": 1666015888000,
                "43909": 1666015888000,
                "43910": 1666015888000 ?. You will only pass key and  value will be from field in another document. So you want  to join two document, find difference and  get average of it. Am I getting it right?

Comment: This answer helped me to solve a similar issue with passing an arbitrary map of id-timestamp values

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to solve this problem too. If I understand you correctly, you would like to use a value returned from the document as the "key" for the hash you have created in params. I think the `params.get()` function might be what you are looking for.

I also changed the script language to `"painless"`. This shouldn't cause any conflicts with the code, but it does enable the two functions that I used.

Here is the link to the Elasticsearch example that uses `params.get()`:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#script-shorten-syntax

I lost the documentation for `int.toString()`, but I tested it and it works as expected.

```
"script": {
              "source": "(doc['lastFixed'] - params.get(doc['id'].toString()))/ (1000*60*60)",
              "lang": "painless",
              "params": {
                "11406": 1614084531000,
                "11473": 1073523856000,
                "11549": 1447461154000,
                "43904": 1666015887000,
                "43905": 1666015887000,
                "43906": 1666015887000,
                "43907": 1666015887000,
                "43908": 1666015888000,
                "43909": 1666015888000,
                "43910": 1666015888000
                }
            }
```